# has_many > through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my models

```
class House
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end


class Tag
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :houses, through: :taggings
end
```

Routes:

```
scope "/:locale" do
resources :houses do
  collection do
    get 'tags/:tag', to: 'houses#index', as: :tag
end
```

House controller:

```
if params[:tag]
      @houses = House.tagged_with(params[:tag])
      @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:tag])
  else
```

House index view

```
- @houses.each do |house|
 = raw house.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_houses_path(t), class: active_class?(tag_houses_path(t)) }.join
```

I want to show the tags with links to taggged pages. This works fine, but when 2 houses are tagged with the same tagname (1 in DB) the view shows 2 the same tags. (By example house 1 and 2 are tagged with "family" i see 2 family tags on the index page) How can i fix this?

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 0):

You want the set of tags that are attached to at least one house, right?

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).select(“distinct(tags.id)”)
```

Comment: when 1 house has a relationship to tag "family" the tag is showed 1 times, when 2 different houses are tag with family > 2 familie tags are showed - when 3 different houses are tag with family > 3 familie tags are showed. So in my case 5 houses are tagged with "family" , 5 tags with the name "family is showed, instead of one family tag. That's the problem...remco

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want your view to exactly look like, but the following statement will give you the unique set of tags associated with all the houses in the view/array:

```
@houses.collect {|h| h.tags.collect {|x| x.name}}.flatten.uniq
```